# Screen width / viewport size: JS to PHP. To manipulate Wordpress output / views

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, screen, viewport

I'm looking to get desktop and mobile functionality in a single Wordpress theme.

There are several solutions available that use a post/get method to send the screen size to php. For example: http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

Now my question is how to implement this in Wordpress. For reference, the PHP is structured like this:

**index.php:**

```
get_header();(header.php)
```

body

```
get_footer();(footer.php)
```

So the question is:

Is there any way to get the screen height/width/viewport into a PHP variable before get_header() gets called from index.php?

There are a few nice WP plugins available to detect mobile devices. My problem with those is that they use mostly user agent data that is hardly reliable. I want my design to change based on the users viewport. And for that i also need to manipulate the Wordpress PHP calls in the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using media queries in CSS instead of programming via php?

This works if you are only targeting modern mobiles such as the iPhone and android devices.

e.g. 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
      href="mobile.css" />

Comment: Yes, this is viable if i only wanted to change markup. However certain elements need to be stopped from loading (using wordpress php calls).

Comment: Also, hiding elements with css will still require it to be loaded, which is not desirable for mobile devices.